# Run Cx_Oracle query in Flask App

Tags: python, sql, oracle, flask, cx-oracle

I am trying to build an app that has a page where I input an id and run a query on that and show results.  Code I have so far is below.

I keep a werkzeug error:

```
BuildError: ('show_entries', {}, None)
```

app.py

```
import cx_Oracle

# Run the query to display the results
@app.route('/matcher/<int:account_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def show_entries(account_id):
    sql = """SELECT item1, 
             item2, 
             item3, 
             item4, 
             item5, 
             item6
             FROM TABLE
             WHERE account_id = ?"""
    c = g.db.cursor()
    c.execute(sql, account_id)
```

Comment: Make sure to access the request variable? Not sure your show_entries is getting a parameter as expected

Comment: maybe because show_entries requires an account_id in  `url_for(show_entries)`

Comment: Edited for errors.  The form action actually routes to the 'entry' method, which is supposed to redirect to 'show_entries' and supply the variable.

Comment: Does modify `return redirect(url_for('show_entries', account_id=account_id))` in entry route work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The addition that makes this work is here.  Everything else in my original code is fine, even if not optimal.

```
        c.execute(sql, account_id=account_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving that error because your `show_entries` method is expecting an `account_id` argument, but your `url_for` call isn't supplying one.

It looks like you're trying to have the `show_entries` method take the `account_id` argument as a GET value in your form, but as part of the URL (not a GET parameter) in the method definition, so you have a mismatch.

You can give the `account_id` variable in the method definition a default value and also check for its presence in the GET parameters:

```
@app.route('/matcher/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/matcher/<int:account_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def show_entries(account_id=0):
    if request.method == 'GET' and not account_id:
        account_id = request.args.get('account_id', 0)
    ...
```

Docs: [url_for](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.url_for), [request.args.get](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/reqcontext/).

Comment: OK, changed it and actually just eliminated the arg from the method. Now I run similar to your suggestion, but I get a TypeError: expecting a dictionary, sequence or keyword args

Comment: Can you nail down which line the error is occurring at?

Comment: turns out this is an Oracle DB thing.  I added c.execute(sql, account_id=account_id) and it works beautifully.  Thanks for the help.